# Django Model class dynamic field creation

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a model form in which m asking for the number of items. once i get the number, there should be that exact number of fields to be filled. How can i do that?

```
class Create_Poll(models.Model):
         heading = models.CharField("Question", max_length=150,blank=False)
         items = models.IntegerField("Number of Items",blank=False)

         i = 0
         for i in range(1,items):
                item = models.CharField("item{i}".format(i=i),max_length=100,blank=False)
                img = models.ImageField("image{i}".format(i=i),upload_to="pics")
```

How can i use the data from the 'items' field??? please help